# 301 redirect via index.php in server root not redirecting properly

Tags: http-status-code-301

I am having issues with a 301 redirect.

I just purchased new shared web hosting. I then set the nameservers (of the domain I wish to redirect) to the new webhost nameservers.

I then uploaded index.php into public_html via cPanel.

Inside index.php I have the following code:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/my_company_page");
?>
```

I then went to the domain and it did not redirect properly in a web browser.

Instead of being redirect to:

```
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/my_company_page
```

I was redirected to:

```
http://www.OriginalDomain.com/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/my_company_page
```

I have done this several times over the past few years....I looked at another website I have (same shared hosting company, same method of 301 redirecting) and it's working perfectly.

Can you guys/gals figure out why it's not working this time?

Could it be due to DNS not propagating (yet) as I just switched over the nameservers.

Comment: You need to use the `http://` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

WHat about header("Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/my_company_page");?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any files in the server. I just want to redirect via index.php. I have done this many times before....but I cannot figure out why this time it is not working.

I'm suspecting it's due to the DNS still propagating....but was hoping someone could confirm that.

Comment: It's not due to the DNS still propagating, it's because you forgot the http prefix. As said above.